# Javascript incrementing a list of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have a list like this:

```
var a=  [['1'[0]],['2'[0]],['3'[0]],['4'[0]]];
```

and if condition that should another variable be equal to either '1','2','3','4' then to increment the values of their list eg:

```
for(var i=0; i<a; i++{
 if(a[i] == z) {
   a[i] += z;
    }
}
```

I know the above code will not work, but how could I get each 'inner' element to incerment?

I'm a javascript novice, so please excuse any errors in the code.

Thanks

Comment: What should be checked against, and what should be incremented? Your current array is invalid.

Comment: Checked against the strings '1' '2' '3' '4' amd the relevant [0] values should be incremented. Thanks

Comment: We assume your array really looks like `var a=  [['1',[0]],['2',[0]],['3',[0]],['4',[0]]];` ?

Comment: Hey... `'1'[0] == '1'` and `'hello'[0] == 'h'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those innermost arrays are at index `[1]` of the first set of inner arrays, assuming your array's actual format is:

```
// Note the commas between the inner elements which you don't have above.
var a = [['1',[0]],['2',[0]],['3',[0]],['4',[0]]];
```

So you're nearly there, you need to access `a[i][1][0]` and incrememnt it `++` rather than `+= z`.

Examples:

```
console.log(a[1][1][0]);
// 0  (at element '2')

// z is the string value you are searching for...
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
  // Match the z search at a[i][0]
  // because a[i] is the current outer array and [0] is its first element
  if(a[i][0] == z) {
    // Increment the inner array value which is index [i][1][0]
    // Because the 1-element inner array is at [i][1] and its first element is [0]
    a[i][1][0]++;
  }
}
```

So for `z = '2'`:

```
// Flattened for readability:
a.toString();
// "1,0,2,1,3,0,4,0"
//-------^^^
```

Then `z = '4'`:

```
// This time the '4' element gets incremented
a.toString();
// "1,0,2,1,3,0,4,1"
//-------^^^-----^^^
```

[Here's a demo on jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/YL99y/2/)

#### Update: This is where the updated value resides:

[image: Console example]

The `Array[1] 0: 1`  is the incremented value for `z == '4'`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I get: [
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
] The arrays don't look like they're incrementing. COuld it be because the value is an integer value not string?

Comment: @user1869421 Yes of course - you need to expand those to examine their inner values. That's why I called toString() to make them visible above.

Comment: [
Array[2]
0: "1"
1: Array[1]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "2"
1: Array[1]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "3"
1: Array[1]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "4"
1: Array[1]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
]

Comment: @user1869421 Keep drilling... Your incremented values are 3 levels in. Those `1: Array[1]` will hold either the original `0` or the incremented `1`.

Comment: Ok, So  I get: [
Array[2]
0: "1"
1: Array[1]
0: 0
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "2"
1: Array[1]
0: 13
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "3"
1: Array[1]
0: 9
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "4"
1: Array[1]
0: 4
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
]                                                                    Thus does: 1: Array[1]
0: 9 represent the incremented value?

Comment: @user1869421 Look at the image above.  This is the console output after my jsfiddle example runs.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. One more thing, if I want to access all those values, I would so so by: a[1][0]?

Comment: @user1869421 You can't access them all at once, you would need to loop.  You can assign them all to a single array like `var b = []; for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) { b.push(a[i][1][0]); }`  The array `b` now holds _only_ the current values from each of the innermost arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to accomplish, but I think it's something like this:

```
var lists = {
    '1': [0],
    '2': [0]
};

function incrementList(listKey, value) {
    if (lists[listKey]) {
        lists[listKey] = lists[listKey].map(function(num) {
            return num + value;
        });
    }        
}

incrementList('1', 2);
console.log(lists['1'][0]); // 2

incrementList('1', 4);
console.log(lists['1'][0]); // 6
```

​